# Respond to an Upload confimation and then process file in Sanic

Tags: python, api, asynchronous, sanic

I am trying to process a file uploaded by the user. However, I want the user to get a response once the upload is completed and terminate the connection but carry on processing the file. My code looks something like this:

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST'])
async def upload(request):
        try:
            file = request.files.get("file")
        except Exception as e:
            return json({"Received": False})

    await process(file)
    return response.text("File has been uploaded successfully")


async def process(file):
    """ Processing File and generate data"""
    ...
    result = await foo(data)
```

In the current framework, the user has to wait until the process completes. I would like the user to get a response saying:

> "File has been uploaded successfully"

and terminate the connection but still continue with process(file).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have two possible solutions here. The first one is going to slightly deviate from your requirements, because it will not terminate the connection. However, I think it is a viable solution, so I offer it as well. If not for your benefit, maybe for someone else that has a similar need.

### Option #1 - Streaming Response

This option is a streaming response where you send back the first part immediately, and then continue on processing with responses as needed. Now, this is obviously somewhat dependent upon *how* much processing we are talking about. If it is going to be somewhat long (pick an arbitrary time, 60s), then this solution may not work.

```py
import asyncio
from functools import partial

from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json, stream

app = Sanic(__name__)


async def process(file, response):
    print(file, flush=True)
    await response.protocol.push_data(b"0x0")
    await response.write("File has been uploaded successfully\n")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await response.write("33% processed\n")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await response.write("66% processed\n")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await response.write("100% processed\n")


@app.post("/")
async def upload(request):
    try:
        file = request.files.get("file")
    except Exception:
        return json({"Received": False})

    return stream(partial(process, file), chunked=False)
```

### Option #2 - Background task

I believe this is more what you are looking for. Immediate response (with a closed connection). We take the `processing` and push it off to the background with `add_task`.

```py
import asyncio
from functools import partial

from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json, text

app = Sanic(__name__)


async def process(file,):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print(f"{file=}", flush=True)


@app.post("/")
async def upload(request):
    try:
        file = request.files.get("file")
    except Exception:
        return json({"Received": False})

    request.app.add_task(process(file))

    return text("File has been uploaded successfully")
```

As another alternative, [here is an example](https://community.sanicframework.org/t/how-to-use-asyncio-queues-in-sanic/166/4?u=ahopkins) that I put together where the handler pushes the task of to a queue, and there is a separate "worker" that is draining the queue and executing the tasks.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Option #2 was exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: Perfect #2 saved me